# How to use input in Google Code Jam using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can i use Google Code Jam's input file `.in` to solve the problem using JavaScript?

Comment: You want to read a file, using JavaScript?

Comment: they provide .io file for input

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think it is an `.in` file, isn't it?

The simplest thing I can think about: open the input file with a program that can read Unix line endings like Notepad++, Wordpad, or almost any software development software and then copy its contents onto a variable in the script.

You can see some solutions of Code Jam 2014 in the following website and make your conclusions of what is the most used system to pass the input file:

- [Language Details: Javascript – Code Jam 2014 Statistics](http://www.go-hero.net/jam/14/languages/JavaScript)

Cheers :-)